# How to fetch stream of reddit comments using flutter package draw library?

Tags: java, python, flutter, dart, draw

I'm trying to fetch a stream of Reddit comments from the subreddit in flutter app. Using Python is very simple using praw library API but when I try using dart wrapper draw I couldn't able to fetch data here is my code which I'm trying to implement

when I print comments I get `I/flutter (30495): Instance of '_ControllerStream<Comment>'`

using this Instance how can I fetch individual streams full of data?

I tried using for each method and fetch value

I ended up getting Error

```
    E/flutter (30495): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: DRAWNotFoundException(Reason: "null", Message: "Bad Request")
E/flutter (30495): #0      parseAndThrowError
package:draw/src/exception_objector.dart:15
E/flutter (30495): #1      Authenticator._request
package:draw/src/auth.dart:230
E/flutter (30495): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (30495): #2      Reddit.get
package:draw/src/reddit.dart:633
E/flutter (30495): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (30495): #3      ListingGenerator.generator._nextBatch
package:draw/…/listing/listing_generator.dart:70
```

in python I can just print comments by looping through this instance

```
for comment in reddit.subreddit('cricket').stream.comments(skip_existing=True):
          print(comment.body)
```

how can I achieve similar result in dart?

there's isn't much information in flutter draw package documentation
here is the definition of this class [draw docc](https://pub.dev/documentation/draw/latest/draw/SubredditStream/comments.html) but its not easily understandable to my requirement , can someone point me out in right direction to achieve this??

Comment: just `comments.listen(print)` or any other callback function like `comments.listen((event) => do_somenthing_with(event));`

Comment: what do you see if you call `comments.listen(print)`?

Comment: what is the stacktrace of the exception?  for example first 6-8 top frames?

Comment: seems it is related to your Reddit library

Comment: I can successfully  print(await reddit.user.me());, it gives all my reddit account details @pskink

Comment: you're right , I was passing '\r' with subreddit name , I just need to pass subreddit name